# Why is this UPDATE statement updating every record?

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have an UPDATE statement that's intended to update a status field for a limited number of records. Here's the statement:

```
UPDATE warehouse_box
SET warehouse_box_status_id = wbsv.warehouse_box_status_id
FROM
    warehouse_box_status_vw wbsv INNER JOIN
    pallet_warehouse_box pwb ON wbsv.warehouse_box_id = pwb.warehouse_box_id INNER JOIN
    routing_shipment_pallet rsp ON pwb.pallet_id = rsp.pallet_id
WHERE
    rsp.date_removed IS NULL
    AND pwb.date_unpalletized IS NULL
    AND rsp.routing_shipment_id = 100002
```

The intended result is for the 6 records that match the WHERE clause to have their statuses updated. What I'm seeing though is that all 200,000+ records are updated. It's as though the WHERE clause is being completely ignored.

Can anyone help shed some light on this for me?

Comment: Replace the UPDATE..SET section with "SELECT * " and tell us how many records are returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not have the table warehouse_box included in the FROM clause.  If you add warehouse_box and join it to warehouse_box_status it should solve your problem.

Comment: Meh. Sure enough. This could be a case study in being too close to the problem... Thanks a bunch. =)

Answer (score 1):

You don't appear to be selecting on `warehouse_box` in the `WHERE` and `INNER JOIN`s -- only from other tables...

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you perform a SELECT with the same FROM and WHERE clauses?

- If you get all 200K rows, there are things you can do to track down the problem from there.
- If you get only the 6 records you want to update, it's time to start looking for triggers that might be updating the whole table.

EDIT: Looks like sharper eyes have already found the problem.

Comment: That's what was troubling me - I only got the 6 rows I expected when I used these clauses in a SELECT, and I know no triggers are running.